# How to create multicolor text in UILabel for iOS 5.1 and below

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I want to create a label that contain text that have to different color. Like this,

[image]

I have done this in iOS 6 using `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString: self.exerciseLbl.attributedText];
[text addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor colorWithRed:(187/255.0) green:(57/255.0) blue:(38/255.0) alpha:1] range: NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
[self.exerciseLbl setAttributedText: text];
```

But this will not work for iOS 5.1 and below. So how could I achieve same result in iOS 5.

Comment: Using attributed string http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**(1)** Build the NSAttributedString *******/

NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Hello World!"];
// for those calls we don't specify a range so it affects the whole string
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
// now we only change the color of "Hello"
 [attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
/**(2)** Affect the NSAttributedString to the OHAttributedLabel *******/
myAttributedLabel.attributedText = attrStr;`
// Use the "Justified" alignment
`myAttributedLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentJustify;`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since iOS 6**, UIKit supports drawing attributed strings, so no extension or replacement is needed.

**From UILabel:**

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText;
```

You just need to build up your NSAttributedString. There are basically two ways:

Append chunks of text with the same attributes - for each part create one NSAttributedString instance and append them to one NSMutableAttributedString

Create attributed text from plain string and then add attributed for given ranges – find the range of your number (or whatever) and apply different color attribute on that.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS lower than 6, you can go ahead with https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel. It provides category and subclassing which worked for me..I hope will be helpful to you too.